# Is there a way to approximate the Laplacian matrix eigenvalues by using random walk like algorithm

Tags: graph-algorithm

It seems to me that many advanced graph analysis algorithm are based on spectral graph analysis, relying more specifically on the Laplacian matrix properties.

I know there are some alternative for clustering that are based on random-walk type algorithms, that make no use of the Laplacian matrix factorization.

I am curious if there exists anything to go a bit further and determine the Laplacian matrix eigenvalues (especially the second one), without using spectral method, but more like wandering on the graph.